# Subversion log for date range on Windows

Tags: windows, svn, command-line, cmd

I've got an issue in subversion. I've written a python script that makes a command line call to subversion to return xml data from the log for further processing. Here's the command that gets run:

```
svn log --xml -r {2018-01-11:2018-03-01} http://my/subverion/repository/
```

This works just fine on Linux and Mac. However, on Windows, I get:

```
svn: E205000: Syntax error in revision argument '2018-01-11:2018-03-01'
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations of quoting, escaping, varying where the curly braces are. Here are a few of the variations I've tried

```
svn log --xml -r "{2018-01-11:2018-03-01}" http://my/subverion/repository/
svn log --xml -r {"2018-01-11":"2018-03-01"} http://my/subverion/repository/
svn log --xml -r {20180111:20180301} http://my/subverion/repository/
svn log --xml -r {2018-01-11}:{2018-03-01} http://my/subverion/repository/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `svn log --xml -r {2018-01-11}:{2018-03-01} http://my/subverion/repository/` isn't working? Because this is the correct syntax. `svn log -r {yyyy-mm-dd}:{yyyy-mm-dd}`. Try that method again because it's working just fine for me. When you try that method again, can you post the error you get?

Comment: @Chris Here's what I get: `$ svn log --xml -r {2018-01-11}:{2018-03-05} http://my/repo
svn: E205000: Syntax error in revision argument '2018-01-11:2018-03-05'`

Comment: I just solved the mystery... This particular machine was set up by my predecessor. They had set up cmd so that it would use the Cygwin binaries for many things, including SVN. I discovered this completely by accident; I saw that Cygwin was installed, and for the heck of it, I ran the svn log command. It worked perfectly. As soon as I installed the straight windows version of SVN and put it ahead of cygwin in the path, it worked just fine.

Comment: Interesting. Glad you resolved it. I had a hunch that it was using something other than the standard CLI. That was the purpose behind my strike-through comment about Powershell, because they all behave differently. Kind of hard to tell from this end though.

Answer (score 1):

(This is in response to your comment reply:)

<s>That's... Strange.. The error you're getting back looks to me as if your curly braces are being stripped for some reason. Are you using Powershell or something like that?</s>

Edit: Light bulb just popped in my head. Just realized you said you were using python for this. When you're using strings in python, you need to escape the curly braces. In order to escape them, you need to double the `{{` and `}}`

Try this command:

```
"svn log --xml -r {{2018-01-11}}:{{2018-03-01}} http://my/subverion/repository/"
```

If you want to include maxmium portability with other command line interfaces like powershell, you can wrap it in quotes:

```
"svn log --xml -r \"{{2018-01-11}}:{2018-03-01}\" http://my/subverion/repository/"
```

Emphasis on the `"` around the the entire date range and curly braces surrounding each date.